# search for pattern in files and delete

Tags: bash, awk, grep

i have a directory contains text files which contains raw http request as following

```
POST /test HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Language: en-US, gHNEY;q=0.9, *;q=0.5
Accept-Charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1;q=0.5, 3AG19;q=0.2, *;q=0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5)
Accept: */*, text/XppPa

param1=ffff&
```

as you see that file named as `2b0c9d9254abb4a775023177380c2598.txt` which is the md5sum of url and this is not the case now but i want to mention it

what i want is search for files which is `not containing parameters` and delete it so the rest of files in that dir would be only files contains params

what i tried is grep unique value found in those files containing params and i found the common thing is char `&` which is written beside param value

so i tried the following command and dosn`t work
`grep -lrIvE '&' . | xargs -0 rm -f --`
the result was
`./2b0c9d9254abb4a775023177380c2598.txt'$'\n': File name too long`

and when i added capital Z to grep deleted all files

so is there anyway to do this and if i could filter the requests (files) contain unique params would be greaaaat

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use the `-0` option of `xargs` without the `-Z` option of `grep`. This would not work. Your problem is that `grep -v` matches all lines not containing `&`. And all your files have at least one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: you cannot use the `-0` option of `xargs` without the `-Z` option of `grep`. The record separators would not match.

Your problem is that `grep -v` matches all lines not containing `&`. And all your files have at least one. Instead of searching non-matching lines you can search for matching ones and delete the files only if none is found:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
  grep -Iq '&' "$f" || printf 'rm -f %s\n' "$f"
done
```

Replace `printf 'rm -f %s\n' "$f"` by `rm -f "$f"` once you will be convinced that it does what you want.

Comment: Why the loop? `find . -type f ! -exec grep -q '&' {} \; -exec echo rm -rf {} +` does the same thing.

Comment: @oguzismail That gets the test backward; try `find . -type f \( -exec grep -q '&' {} \; -o -print \)`, and if it prints the right names, replace `-print` with `-delete`.

Comment: @Gordon Yeah, thanks. Updated it, parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: @oguzismail Without the parentheses, it'll delete any subdirectories (because they fail the `-type f` test).

Comment: @Gordon I mean negating the first exec in my command is enough, there is no need for parentheses and or

Comment: @GordonDavisson "_Without the parentheses, it'll delete any subdirectories (because they fail the -type f test)._": I thought the default operator between expressions was a `and`. Was I wrong?

Comment: @oguzismail Ah, I get it; negating the `-exec grep` should work fine.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet My version has an `-o` ("or") operator between the `-exec grep` and `-delete`; the implicit "and" has higher precedence than `-o`, so without the parentheses it would've been: (it's a file AND contains "&") OR delete it -- which would delete everything that isn't a file OR doesn't contain "&".

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ah, I see, it was about your proposal, not that from oguzismail. Thanks.

Comment: thx @RenaudPacalet for the solution it working probably